# Перемещение окна без границ за определенный участок (в моем случае за виджет QFrame)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, mousemoveevent, qframe

**main.py**:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QPushButton, QMainWindow, QFrame, QLabel, QMenu
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtCore import QPoint
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets as qtw
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtSvg import QSvgWidget, QSvgRenderer


class Ui_MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    '''  Основное Окно Программы '''

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.mwidget = QMainWindow(self)
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.Tool | QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint | QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
        self.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 200, 200, 200))

        self.Label = QtWidgets.QFrame(self)
        self.Label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 30, 120, 80))
        self.Label.setStyleSheet("#Label {\n"
"background-color: #000000;\n"
"}\n")
        self.Label.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.Label.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.Label.setObjectName("Label")

        # --- Показать Окно ---
        self.show()

    # --- Действие при нажатии мыши ---
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
            self.oldPos = event.globalPos()

    # --- Изменение положения мыши ---
    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        delta = QPoint (event.globalPos() - self.oldPos)
        self.move(self.x() + delta.x(), self.y() + delta.y())
        self.oldPos = event.globalPos()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Ui_MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Мне нужно перемещать ***Окно А***, в котором ***Фрейм Б***, только за **`Фрейм Б`**.
Сейчас *Окно A* перетаскивается как за *А* так и за *Б*.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если вам действительно нужна помощь, опубликуйте минимальный пример, который можно скопировать и запустить и который демонстрирует вашу проблему.  А также подробнее опишите, что и куда вы хотите переместить.

Comment: S. Nick,   Учту Ваше пожелание. Вопрос дополнил.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вам надо перемещать Фрейм Б, вы должны в отдельном классе для Фрейма Б прописать те же методы. Возможно в этом классе вам надо будет прописать ограничения перемещения мыши, чтобы не перетаскивать Фрейм Б за пределы Фрейма А.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QPushButton, QMainWindow, QFrame, QLabel, QMenu
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtCore import QPoint
#from PyQt5 import QtWidgets as qtw
#from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
#from PyQt5.QtSvg import QSvgWidget, QSvgRenderer


class Frame(QtWidgets.QFrame):                                       # +++
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Frame, self).__init__(parent)

   # --- Действие при нажатии мыши ---
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
            self.oldPos = event.globalPos()

   # --- Изменение положения мыши ---
    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        delta = QPoint (event.globalPos() - self.oldPos)
        self.move(self.x() + delta.x(), self.y() + delta.y())
        self.oldPos = event.globalPos()        


class Ui_MainWindow(QMainWindow):
   # --- Основное Окно Программы ---
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

#        self.mwidget = QMainWindow(self)
#        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.Tool | QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint | QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint | QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
        self.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 200, 200, 200))

        self.Label = Frame(self)                                # - QtWidgets.QFrame(self)
        self.Label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 30, 120, 80))
        self.Label.setStyleSheet("#Label {background-color: #0000ff;}")
        self.Label.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.Label.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.Label.setObjectName("Label")

       # --- Показать Окно ---
        self.show()

   # --- Действие при нажатии мыши ---
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
            self.oldPos = event.globalPos()

   # --- Изменение положения мыши ---
    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        delta = QPoint (event.globalPos() - self.oldPos)
        self.move(self.x() + delta.x(), self.y() + delta.y())
        self.oldPos = event.globalPos()


# --- Запуск Окна Программы ---
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Ui_MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Update**

> мне не нужно перемещать фрейм Б в окне А. мне нужно переместить окно А но только если левая клавиша мыши была нажата на фрейме Б. чтобы перемещение не работало на окне А.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QPushButton, QMainWindow, QFrame, QLabel, QMenu
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtCore import QPoint
#from PyQt5 import QtWidgets as qtw
#from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
#from PyQt5.QtSvg import QSvgWidget, QSvgRenderer


class Ui_MainWindow(QMainWindow):
   # --- Основное Окно Программы ---
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint | QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
        self.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 200, 200, 200))

        self.Label = QtWidgets.QFrame(self) 
        self.Label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 30, 120, 80))
        self.Label.setStyleSheet("#Label {background-color: #0000ff;}")
        self.Label.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.Label.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.Label.setObjectName("Label")

       # --- Показать Окно ---
        self.show()

   # --- Действие при нажатии мыши ---
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.oldPos = event.globalPos()

   # --- Изменение положения мыши ---
    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):

        # +++
        if (self.Label.mapToGlobal(QPoint(0,0)).x()>self.oldPos.x()      or\
            self.oldPos.x()>self.Label.mapToGlobal(QPoint(0,0)).x()+120) or\
            (self.Label.mapToGlobal(QPoint(0,0)).y()>self.oldPos.y()     or\
            self.oldPos.y()>self.Label.mapToGlobal(QPoint(0,0)).y()+80) : 
            return 

        delta = QPoint (event.globalPos() - self.oldPos)
        self.move(self.x() + delta.x(), self.y() + delta.y())
        self.oldPos = event.globalPos()


# --- Запуск Окна Программы ---
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Ui_MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: мне не нужно перемещать фрейм Б в окне А. мне нужно переместить окно А но только если левая клавиша мыши была нажата на фрейме Б. чтобы перемещение не работало на окне А.

Comment: @biomotor я добавил обновление, пробуйте.

Comment: Работает, А без привязки к 120 и 80 никак?

Comment: @biomotor это расположение фрейма Б относительно окна А и его размеры `self.Label.geometry()`. Сохраните в переменные их значения, если вам надо.

Comment: а ведь в self.Label.geometry() насколько я понимаю уже итак используются размеры начальных точек и габаритов... self.Label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 30, 120, 80)) зачем дублировать? как можно сослаться на self.Label.setGeometry полностью ? я просто хочу чтобы данная часть кода ссылалась на self.Label.setGeometry и чтобы тупо меняя размер в Label она сразу меняла и там. а слишком много переменных это тоже загруженность кода, а так буду знать что просто вставив код и присвоив фрейму он будет работать.

Comment: @biomotor в конструкторе: `self.w, self.h, = 120, 80` и `self.Label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 30, self.w, self.h))` .  В методе `mouseMoveEvent`  - `if (self.Label.mapToGlobal(QPoint(0,0)).x()>self.oldPos.x()      or\
            self.oldPos.x()>self.Label.mapToGlobal(QPoint(0,0)).x()+self.w) or\
            (self.Label.mapToGlobal(QPoint(0,0)).y()>self.oldPos.y()     or\
            self.oldPos.y()>self.Label.mapToGlobal(QPoint(0,0)).y()+self.h) :`